# Ajax updating data without refreshing to another page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having trouble with getting the right handler to get the ajax working to update data.

This is how I have my **'submission' form**, appended input fields and submit button:

```
var ctrno='';
var refno='';
$('#containers').delegate("a.edit","click", function(e) {
  ctrno = $(this).closest("td").attr("data-id");
  refno = $(this).closest("td").siblings().attr("data-refno");
  var html = "<div class='editctrno'><input type='hidden' class='ctr' id='refid' name='refid' value='"+refno+"'>" +
        "<input name='ctrno' class='ctr' id='ctrno' class='btn btn-primary' type='text' value='"+ctrno+"'>" +
        "<p><input id='ctrsubmit' type='button' value='Update'> <a href='#' class='canceledit btn btn-default'>Cancel</a></p></div>";
$(this).closest("td").html(html);

$('#containers').delegate("a.canceledit", "click", function() {
    var curctrno = $(this).closest("td").attr("data-id");
    $(this).closest(".editctrno").html("<a class='edit'>"+curctrno+"</a>");
});
});
```

This is my **ajax call**:

```
$('#ctrsubmit').click(function() {
  var meikorefno = $('input#refid').val();
  var ctrnum = $('input#ctrno').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/containers",     
    data: {'refid' : refno, 'ctrno' : ctrnum },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("success!");
    }
  });
});
```

Nothing is happening with the 'Update' button. I tried an .submit() to no avail. Before I had it in a form format: `<form method='post' id='editctrno'>....</form>` but that will just refresh the page despite me putting an `e.preventDefault();` object. What am I doing wrong?

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/727dapyx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$('#ctrsubmit').click()` doesn't work for live-updated html-code. you have to use the `.on` handler instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ctrsubmit', function(e){});
```

### update

you used the `.on` handler wrong in your JSFiddle:

**change:**

`$("#ctrsubmit").on("click", function(e) {});`

**to**

`$(document).on("click", "#ctrsubmit", function(e) {});`

working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/e4370r43/)

Comment: I have tried this and it's not working either. Nothing happens when clicking the 'update' button.

Comment: @SamYoung can you `console.log()` or `alert()` something in your click function, to see if it really isn't executed?

Comment: they are both not executing.

Comment: @SamYoung well, hard to help you, when we can only see a part of your code. would you mind making a JSFiddle?

Comment: @SamYoung see my updated answer. you just used the `.on` handler wrong.